# Session login/logout ASP to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just a beginner in PHP. I'm making a website, and it needs to store the time for login and logout of every user. I found [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1314/Tracking-users-login-logout-times-on-your-site) for it but it's in ASP.

I tried to make it into PHP but I'm unknowledgeable what will I put in the `INSERT INTO` of `sessionid` and `logintime`.

Table name: userlogtime
logid, userid, sessionid, logintime, logouttime, offline

Here's my code:

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 include 'dbheader.php';

 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

 //Error handlers
 //Check if inputs are empty 
 if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please fill out the following");
    window.history.back();
    </script>';
 exit();
 } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck < 1) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login error");
    window.history.back();
    </script>';
     //set the user id value from the Members table in a session variable
    $_SESSION('member') = $row($userid);
    $sql ="UPDATE userlogtime SET offline=True WHERE offline=False AND userid="$_SESSION('member')"";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userlogtime (userid, sessionid, logintime) VALUES ('$_SESSION('member'),      );";

    exit();
 } else {
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //De-hashing the password
    $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
    if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login error");
    window.history.back();
    </script>';
    exit();
    } elseif($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $row['Role'];
            $_SESSION['image'] = $row['image'];

            if($_SESSION['role'] == "User"){
                header("Location: user.php");
                exit();
            }
    }
}
}
}
} else {
  header("Location: user.php?login=error");
  exit();
  }
```

Comment: What is the type of login time field. If timestamp use MySQL now() function. Use php session_id() function to get session id

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "INSERT INTO userlogtime (userid, sessionid, logintime) VALUES ('$_SESSION('member'), ".session_id().",now());";